# How to merge two consecutive rows and form a new column?

Tags: pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a DF(collected from an accounting software) which looks like this.

```
    Serial || Date || Particulars || Price
    --------------------------------------
      1    || 0308 || Andrew      || 100
      2    || NaN  || Gloves      || NaN
      3    || 0408 || Johnson     || 50
      4    || NaN  || Wicket      || NaN
```

I want to merge the 2 consecutive rows and make a new column 'Product' with 2nd rows 'Particulars' value.
The expected output should look like ---

```
    Serial || Date || Particulars || Price || Product
    -------------------------------------------------
      1    || 0308 || Andrew      || 100   || Gloves
      3    || 0408 || Johnson     || 50    || Wicket
```

How do I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These answers are predicated on the format of the dataframe always presenting pairs of rows that follow the same pattern presented by OP.  First row shows a person, second row shows a product and date, price columns are NaN.

#### Use `shift` then `dropna`

```
df.assign(Product=df.Particulars.shift(-1)).dropna()

   Serial   Date Particulars  Price Product
0       1  308.0      Andrew  100.0  Gloves
2       3  408.0     Johnson   50.0  Wicket
```

---

#### `join`

Same exact thing but different

```
df.join(df.Particulars.shift(-1).rename('Product')).dropna()
```

---

#### Details

Per Request

- `df.Particulars.shift(-1)` brings all members of the Particulars column back one row

  ```
  0     Gloves
  1    Johnson
  2     Wicket
  3        NaN
  Name: Particulars, dtype: object
  ```
- When I assign this to the existing dataframe `df.assign(Product=df.Particulars.shift(-1))` it adds a column with a new name `'Product'` where the values are the shifted Particulars.

  ```
     Serial   Date Particulars  Price  Product
  0       1  308.0      Andrew  100.0   Gloves
  1       2    NaN      Gloves    NaN  Johnson
  2       3  408.0     Johnson   50.0   Wicket
  3       4    NaN      Wicket    NaN      NaN
  ```
- All that's left is to drop the rows withe the `NaN` values and we have what is presented above.

---

#### Inspired by [@QuangHoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56046250/2336654)

I don't need to depend on `dropna` if I slice every other row

```
df.assign(Product=df.Particulars.shift(-1))[::2]
```

Or even more terse

```
df[::2].assign(Product=[*df.Particulars[1::2]])
```

---

#### One way to do it

This was the first way I thought of and it's gross

```
i = np.flatnonzero(df.Price.notna())
j = i + 1

df.iloc[i].assign(Product=df.iloc[j].Particulars.values)

   Serial   Date Particulars  Price Product
0       1  308.0      Andrew  100.0  Gloves
2       3  408.0     Johnson   50.0  Wicket
```

Comment: @AvikDutta does what I've added to my post suffice?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Let me try it on my actual dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Try `shift` and drop the even rows:

```
df['Product'] = df['Particulars'].shift(-1)
df = df.loc[0:len(df):2]
```

Comment: I like this answer which is why I up voted it.  However, you don't need `len(df)` in your slice specification.  `df[::2].assign(Product=df.Particulars[1::2].values)`.  This answer also doesn't depend on `NaN` and `dropna`.

Comment: @piRSquared Good points. Thanks. Learned a new thing about slicing.

Answer (score 1):

ugly but straightforward:

```
ans = df[~pd.isna(df.Date)].copy()
ans['product'] = df[pd.isna(df.Date)].Particulars.values
```

#### output

```
        Date  Particulars  Price  product
Serial                                  
1       308.0      Andrew  100.0  Gloves
3       408.0     Johnson   50.0  Wicket
```