# Merging consecutive rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge consecutive rows into one row in a pandas dataframe.
This is the table I currently have:

| id_number | document_number | value | log_date | co | delay(days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4100000739 | 106782327 | 0 | 1/13/2017 14:23 | A |  |
| 4100000739 | 106788192 | 1 | 1/13/2017 16:39 | A | 0 |
| 4100000740 | 106787500 | 0 | 1/13/2017 16:14 | A |  |
| 4100000740 | 106788227 | F | 1/13/2017 16:40 | A | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | B |  |
| 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | B | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | B | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | C |  |
| 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | C | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | C | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | C |  |
| 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | C | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | C | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | D |  |
| 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | D | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | D | 0 |

desired output:

| id_number | document_numb | value1 | value2 | log_date1 | log_date2 | co | delay(days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4100000739 | 106782327 | 0 | 1 | 1/13/2017 14:23 | 1/13/2017 16:39 | A | 0 |
| 4100000740 | 106787500 | 0 | F | 1/13/2017 16:14 | 1/13/2017 16:14 | A | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 0 | 2/13/2017 14:22 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | B | 0 |
| 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | B | 0 |

etc.
Essentially, the delay column in the first table contains the date difference between the log_date on row(X+1) and row(X). So the delay  in the second column should contain the value of the row row(x+1).
the mergin of the rows is done based on id_number and co. I really hope this is clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two consecutive rows and form a new column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046078/how-to-merge-two-consecutive-rows-and-form-a-new-column)

Comment: this is very close to named aggregations,  grouping by **id_number**. However you do not describe logic for *4100000743* - why two rows,  not more, not one

Comment: @gtomer no not exactly.

Comment: @RobRaymond hey. I put etc at the end implying that the logic follows in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `groupby()` **id_number** for logic
- `concat(axis=1)` of nth and (n+1)th rows
- `rename(columns=...)` to output column names you want
- use `head()` to remove last row in group that does not have an (n+1) row

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id_number~document_number~value~log_date~co~delay(days)
4100000739~106782327~0~1/13/2017 14:23~A~
4100000739~106788192~1~1/13/2017 16:39~A~0
4100000740~106787500~0~1/13/2017 16:14~A~
4100000740~106788227~F~1/13/2017 16:40~A~0
4100000743~109334630~N~2/13/2017 14:22~B~
4100000743~109358034~0~2/14/2017 9:24~B~0
4100000743~109358735~1~2/14/2017 9:37~B~0
4100000743~109334630~N~2/13/2017 14:22~C~
4100000743~109358034~0~2/14/2017 9:24~C~0
4100000743~109358735~1~2/14/2017 9:37~C~0
4100000743~109334630~N~2/13/2017 14:22~C~
4100000743~109358034~0~2/14/2017 9:24~C~0
4100000743~109358735~1~2/14/2017 9:37~C~0
4100000743~109334630~N~2/13/2017 14:22~D~
4100000743~109358034~0~2/14/2017 9:24~D~0
4100000743~109358735~1~2/14/2017 9:37~D~0"""), sep="~")


def mergerows(df):
    return pd.concat([df.rename(columns={"value":"value1","log_date":"log_date1"}).drop(columns="delay(days)"), 
           df.shift(-1).loc[:,["value","log_date","delay(days)"]].rename(columns={"value":"value2","log_date":"log_date2"})
                     ], axis=1).head(len(df)-1)


dfc = df.groupby("id_number", as_index=False).apply(mergerows).reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | id_number | document_number | value1 | log_date1 | co | value2 | log_date2 | delay(days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4100000739 | 106782327 | 0 | 1/13/2017 14:23 | A | 1 | 1/13/2017 16:39 | 0 |
| 1 | 4100000740 | 106787500 | 0 | 1/13/2017 16:14 | A | F | 1/13/2017 16:40 | 0 |
| 2 | 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | B | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | 0 |
| 3 | 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | B | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | 0 |
| 4 | 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | B | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | nan |
| 5 | 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | C | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | 0 |
| 6 | 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | C | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | 0 |
| 7 | 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | C | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | nan |
| 8 | 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | C | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | 0 |
| 9 | 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | C | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | 0 |
| 10 | 4100000743 | 109358735 | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | C | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | nan |
| 11 | 4100000743 | 109334630 | N | 2/13/2017 14:22 | D | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | 0 |
| 12 | 4100000743 | 109358034 | 0 | 2/14/2017 9:24 | D | 1 | 2/14/2017 9:37 | 0 |

Comment: Hey thanks. I get the idea of what youre trying to do however the result for id_number = 4100000743 are not correct. consecutive rows should be merged, the first with the second, second with third, third with fourth etc. Also the mergin should only happen with same id_numbers. new set of id numbers start a different merging.

Comment: ok now you have fully defined logic it becomes straight forward

Comment: Thanks very much. It works as expected. I have marked as the correct answer:)